# Office.js: ContentControl in table broken after inserting row

Tags: javascript, ms-word, office365, office-js, office-addins

I'm using Microsoft® Word for Microsoft 365 MSO (Version 2307 Build 16.0.16626.20170) 64-bit - which means that Word API is [version 1.5](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/requirement-sets/word/word-api-requirement-sets?view=common-js-preview).
Running add-inn sample "Office Add-in Task Pane project" with JavaScript from Microsoft Tutorial: "**Create a Word task pane add-in**" - [page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/tutorials/word-tutorial?view=common-js-preview).
[image]

Here is my "RUN" button on-click handler:

```
export async function run() {
  return Word.run(async (context) => {
    /**
     * Create Table
     */
    const data = [
      ["Tokyo", "Beijing", "Seattle"],
      ["Apple", "Orange", "Pineapple"]
    ];
    const table = context.document.body.insertTable(2, 3, "Start", data);
    table.styleBuiltIn = Word.BuiltInStyleName.gridTable5Dark_Accent2;
    table.styleFirstColumn = false;

    /**
     * Selecting first row and inserting ContentControl
     */
    table.rows.getFirst().select("Select");
    let range = context.document.getSelection();
    range.insertContentControl();
    /**
     * At this point ContentControl covers only first row
     */

    /**
     * Inserting new row to the end
     */
    const firstTable = context.document.body.tables.getFirst();
    firstTable.addRows("End", 1, [["New", "Row", "Here"]]);

    /**
     * At this point ContentControl spread for all rows :(    
    */

   await context.sync();
});
```

In the code above only the first row is inside content control. But after adding a new row firstTable.addRows("End", 1, [["New", "Row", "Here"]]) all rows become inside content control. How to fix it?
[image]

Comment: I added the [office-js] tag , so maybe the right people will see it. Please edit your question to include the version of the office-js API you are using.FWIW I was able to reproduce this problem, and I do think the office-js API is doing the wrong thing. It would be harder than using AddRows, but you might be able to copy/paste the last row, remove any new ContentControl that was created and replace the content with the content you want in the new row.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, specified Word API version :)

Comment: @jonsson unfortunately I can't find how to do it with JavaScript API, only with VBA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some back-and-forth with Office.js the solution (or I would say workaround for Microsoft bug) was found:

1. Insert Content Control in desired row in the table
2. Get ooxml string from the table and save it into temp var
3. Delete ooxml from the table (very important step)
4. Using DOMParser, convert ooxml string to document
5. Using xpath, copy/paste desired row inside ooxml document
6. Using XMLSerializer serialize ooxml back to string
7. Insert ooxml string back to table with "Replace" option
8. ...
9. Profit

Answer (score 2):

Before adding new row you could remove the content control, add a row, and then re-add content control to the original range.

```
export async function run() {
  return Word.run(async (context) => {
    /**
     * Create Table
     */
    const data = [
      ["Tokyo", "Beijing", "Seattle"],
      ["Apple", "Orange", "Pineapple"]
    ];
    const table = context.document.body.insertTable(2, 3, "Start", data);
    table.styleBuiltIn = Word.BuiltInStyleName.gridTable5Dark_Accent2;
    table.styleFirstColumn = false;

    /**
     * Selecting first row and inserting ContentControl
     */
    const firstRow = table.rows.getFirst();
    firstRow.load("values");
    await context.sync();

    const range = firstRow.getRange("Whole");
    const contentControl = range.insertContentControl();
    contentControl.tag = "tempTag";

    await context.sync();

    /**
     * Remove the Content Control Temporarily
     */
    const tempContentControl = context.document.contentControls.getByTag("tempTag").getFirst();
    tempContentControl.delete(false); // false means the content within the control will not be deleted
    await context.sync();

    /**
     * Inserting new row to the end
     */
    const firstTable = context.document.body.tables.getFirst();
    firstTable.addRows("End", 1, [["New", "Row", "Here"]]);

    await context.sync();

    /**
     * Re-add the Content Control
     */
    range.insertContentControl();

    await context.sync();
  });
}
```

`tag` is for identifying content control that needs to be temporarily removed. After the new row is added, content control is re-added to the original range.