# How to copy/paste table row in MS Word with JavaScript API?

Tags: javascript, ms-word, office365, office-js, office-addins

I'm trying to duplicate a row in a Word table. I saw that it's easy to do with VBA, but I'm using [word-js api v.1.5](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/requirement-sets/word/word-api-requirement-sets?view=word-js-1.5). How can I do it?

Comment: Try working with the Common APIs in Office.js, such as [TableData](https://learn.microsoft.com/javascript/api/office/office.tabledata)

Comment: @RickKirkham thank you for reply, TableData, or even TableUpdateData works with simple values like strings inside table. I my case each cell can have complex structure with ContentControls, other tables or lists.

Comment: Just answered this question in another one about [broken content controls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76973084/office-js-contentcontrol-in-table-broken-after-inserting-row/77007616)